# Encountering Routing Problems with Axios POST Requests in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, express, axios, expo, express-router

**Issue**:
I'm developing a blood donation-related React Native Expo project, and I'm encountering a routing issue when I try to make a POST request using Axios.

**Description**:
I have a `handleSignup` function in my `SignupScreen.js` that sends a POST request to an API endpoint for user registration. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```js
const handleSignup = () => {
  const user = {
    // user data...
  };

  axios
    .post("http://192.168.66.184:19000/register", user)
    .then((response) => {
      // Handle response...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle error...
    });
}
```

**Error:**
However, when I run my app and press the signup button, I get the following error message: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404." When I try to access "http://192.168.66.184:19000/register" in my browser, I get "Cannot GET /register," but I don't get any error when I visit "http://192.168.66.184:19000/"."http://192.168.66.184:19000/" this load on my browser successfully.

**Project Structure**:
Here's the structure of my project for reference:

```
bloodDonor/
├── api/
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── models/
│   │   ├── donorInfoModel.js
│   │   └── donorRequestModel.js
│   ├── package.json
│   └── package-lock.json
├── App.js
├── app.json
├── ... (other project files)
```

**API Configuration**:
I have an API server running in `api/index.js`, which listens on port 3000.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb+srv://....@cluster0.wu2cqze.mongodb.net/", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error Connecting to MongoDB");
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server is running on port 3000");
  });

const Donor = require('./models/donorInfoModel');
const bloodReqs = require('./models/donorRequestModel'); 
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password, batch, department, bloodGrp, donationNum, donationDate, mobile, address} = req.body;

    const existingUser = await Donor.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email already registered" });
    }

    //create a new user
    const newUser = new Donor({ name, email, password, batch, department, bloodGrp, donationNum, donationDate, mobile, address});

    //generate and store the verification token
    newUser.verificationToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");

    //save the  user to the database
    await newUser.save();

    //send the verification email to the user
    sendVerificationEmail(newUser.email, newUser.verificationToken);

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Registration successful" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error registering user", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "error registering user" });
  }
});



const sendVerificationEmail = async (email, verificationToken) => {
  //create a nodemailer transporter

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "....",
      pass: "....",
    },
  });

  //compose the email message
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "threads.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "Email Verification",
    text: `please click the following link to verify your email http://10.0.2.2:3000/verify/${verificationToken}`,
  };

  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error sending email", error);
  }
};


// verification 
app.get("/verify/:token", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.params.token;

    const user = await User.findOne({ verificationToken: token });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
    }

    user.verified = true;
    user.verificationToken = undefined;
    await user.save();

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Email verified successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error getting token", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Email verification failed" });
  }
});

const generateSecretKey = () => {
  const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex");
  return secretKey;
};
const secretKey = generateSecretKey();

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid email" });
    }

    if (user.password !== password) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid password" });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secretKey);

    res.status(200).json({ token });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Login failed" });
  }
});
```

My database is connected successfully.
$api: npm start

```
> api@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
server is running on port 3000
Connected to MongoDB
```

**Troubleshooting**:
I've also tried using `http://localhost:3000/` and also try to use `http://localhost:19000/` but the issue remains. I'm running the app on a physical Android device as an emulator and Ubuntu is my operating system.

**Question**:
How can I resolve this routing issue and successfully make a POST request to the `/register` endpoint in my React Native Expo project?

Comment: have you try to change `axios.post` to `axios.get`

Comment: @talhamaqsood890 I try this but face the same issue.

Comment: Maybe it's the problem that you were using http instead of https.
Checkout my comment -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77428797/expo-build-apk-does-not-fetch-data-like-the-development-app#comment136504020_77428797

Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element